# EPPlus set default sorting on a column

Tags: excel, epplus

How would i set default sorting on a column using EPPLUS?

I can not find any 'sort' column.

What is the best course of action, i cannot sort them from the database, i need to have them sorting in the 'excel'.

Comment: You can't with EPPlus, see https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/14791